# Periodically very slow execution of simplest queries

Tags: mysql, innodb, performance, troubleshooting, slow-log

Inspecting MySQL slow query log I found out that in certain periods of time there are a bunch of queries in log which are supposed to be very fast but were actually very slow.

For example:

```
# User@Host: ***[***] @  [***]
# Query_time: 14.532574  Lock_time: 0.050162 Rows_sent: 18  Rows_examined: 18
SET timestamp=1483014348;
CALL get_games();
# User@Host: ***[***] @  [***]
# Query_time: 15.287524  Lock_time: 0.008114 Rows_sent: 18  Rows_examined: 18
SET timestamp=1483014348;
CALL get_games();
# User@Host: ***[***] @  [***]
# Query_time: 15.637633  Lock_time: 0.027461 Rows_sent: 18  Rows_examined: 18
SET timestamp=1483014348;
CALL get_games();
# User@Host: ***[***] @  [***]
# Query_time: 15.070246  Lock_time: 0.050137 Rows_sent: 18  Rows_examined: 18
SET timestamp=1483014348;
CALL get_games();
```

Where procedure get_games is just a simple SELECT from table with 18 rows and normally executes immediately.

```
MySQL [db_receipt]> show create table game;
MySQL [db_receipt]> CREATE TABLE `game` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Гейтовый идентификатор игры',
  `product_name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'Название игры для печати в квитанции',
  `arm_url` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Url в АРМ-е',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=20 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

MySQL [db_receipt]> show create procedure get_games;
+-----------+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
| Procedure | sql_mode | Create Procedure                                                                                                                       | character_set_client | collation_connection | Database Collation |
+-----------+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
| get_games |          | CREATE DEFINER=`receipt_adm`@`%` PROCEDURE `get_games`()
l_proc: begin

    SELECT  `product_id`, `product_name` FROM `game`;

end | utf8                 | utf8_unicode_ci      | utf8_unicode_ci    |
+-----------+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+----
```

There are also a lot of other slow simple queries such select a row by primary key etc.

What can cause such a performance degradation? How can I troubleshoot a problem to find a reason?

**EDIT**: MySQL Server has very good characteristics and normally queries run fast. It's a production server under high load.

**EDIT2**: Another slow query example (on another database), also very simple:

```
# Time: 161230 12:13:39
# User@Host: ***[***] @ *** [***]
# Query_time: 4.780936  Lock_time: 0.000069 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
use ***;
SET timestamp=1483089219;
update ShoppingCart set cartStatus='ACQUIRED' where shoppingCartId=23423;
```

Comment: Is the server running on a mobile phone from 2002?  All kidding aside, there are a lot of possible reasons.  Have you checked anything?

Comment: It's a production server with very good characteristics but last weeks we see some anomaly. Normally this queries run very fast (as it should) but from time to time you see this...
I am developer and I don't have direct access to production server to make some performance check or troubleshooting but I am very interesting what can most likely cause this.

Comment: Do you use `BEGIN...COMMIT` and other statements around this `CALL`?  What does `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;` say when it happens?  I see that the timestamp is identical; how many copies were running at the same time?

Comment: It runs with autocommit off with READ COMMITED transaction isolation level. SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS shows nothing special. Actually this query is just a one example, I am pretty sure problem is not in this query, I just show it to give an example that most slow queries are very simple.

Answer (score 0):

*Probably*... Some other transaction hit that table in some locking way.  And it took 15+ seconds for it to finish.  Meanwhile, all of your 'users' were running this SP, but being held up until the lock was released.

If you can catch it when it happens, do `SHOW PROCESSLIST`, and look for the queries *other than* `CALL get_games`.  One of them is likely to be the villain.

Once you have found it, there may be several actionss to consider...

- Not grabbing the table so forcefully; that is, moving it outside its transaction, or otherwise changing the SQL.  (This seems like the likely answer.)
- Not having every user always call get_games.
- Other

`SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` is likely to show the villain, also, but you have to run it during or very soon after the problem.

I dislike using `autocommit=0` because I might forget to eventually do `COMMIT`.  That is a hard-to-find bug.  I prefer to explicitly say `BEGIN` as a reminder that I need to place the `COMMIT` some time really soon.  I even insist  (for my code) of putting both in the same subroutine.

Simply moving the `CALL` to before the `BEGIN` may solve it (unless you are also modifying the table in the transaction).

Comment: Query_time: 14.532574  Lock_time: 0.050162
As far as I understand: Lock_time - time that query wait to execute because of other query, it's pretty small here actually I don't understand why it is > 0 because it should be consistent non-locking read so nothing to wait here...
And query_time is actual query time and I think problem is here.

Comment: I don't think `Lock_time` takes transaction locks into account.

Comment: `Query_time` is elapsed time, including all kinds of delays.

Comment: According to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19036176/how-to-interpret-slow-query-log-information-generated-by-mysql
Lock time is the time spend before the query starts executing. I.e., time waiting for other threads to give up their locks on the data the current query needs to lock.

Comment: How can I forcefully grab table lock if I just make consistent non-locking read?

Comment: Search your code for all other references (read or write) to that table.  Then identify the length of the transactions they are in.

Comment: `Lock_time` dates back before InnoDB existed; I don't trust its semantics to have been updated when InnoDB was added.  (Just a gut feeling.)

Comment: I am sure nobody locks this table. It was filled with data once, nobody updates it, the only read query is simple select: SELECT `id` INTO v_game_id FROM `game` WHERE `product_id` = a_game_id;